# How to expand UIButton frame in select mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an small UIButton and set Background for select state by:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"butBG.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

`butBG.png imageSize > button.frame`. 
And I want to expand `UIButton.frame` equal to imageSize when `[button setSelected:YES];`
After that back to origin Frame when `[button setSelected:NO];`

How can I do that? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: use button "btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);" while YES and btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8,0.8);
while NO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) check the button state on button click using `btn.isSelected`.

2) If `btn.isSelected` is true then set the button size similar to image size else set the button size which you want on normal state.

Answer (score 1):

you could make a category for the button and override the `setSelected` method to change the frame size of the button depending on the state

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the state of your button and resize it when it changes

in viewDidLoad (or do the equivalent using the interface builder)

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonStateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonStateChanged:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside | UIControlEventTouchCancel)];
```

create the method

```
- (IBAction)myButtonStateChanged:(UIButton *)sender {
  if (sender.selected) {
     sender.frame = BIG_SIZE_FRAME;
  }
  else {
     sender.frame = NORMAL_SIZE_FRAME;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)setButtonframe:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (button.selected)
    {
        [button setFrame:largeFrame];

    }
    else
    {
        [button setFrame:smallFrame];

    }
}
```

Call
[self setButtonframe:sender];
in the action of button click

Answer (score 0):

GO for this...

```
- (IBAction)paymentBtnCliked:(id)sender {

if ([sender isSelected]) {
     // configure same object as per requirement
    [paymentBtn setSelected:NO];
}else{
     // configure same object as per requirement
     [paymentBtn setSelected:YES];

}
}
```